# Collision detection problem in java. intersectsWith method always return true

Tags: java, collision-detection

I am currently working on a game but I have a problem with my collision detection:

Those are my implemented methods:

```
public boolean intersectsWith(GameObject other) {   
    if(getTopRightPoint(this)[1] < getBottomLeftPoint(other)[1]
            || getBottomLeftPoint(this)[1] > getTopRightPoint(other)[1]) {
        return false;
    }
    if(getTopRightPoint(this)[0] < getBottomLeftPoint(other)[0]
            || getBottomLeftPoint(this)[0] > getTopRightPoint(other)[0]) {
        return false;
    }

    System.out.println("COLLISION BETWEEN " + this.getClass().getSimpleName() + " and "+ other.getClass().getSimpleName());
    return true;

}

private double[] getBottomLeftPoint(GameObject gameObject){
    return new double[] {gameObject.actualPosition[0], gameObject.actualPosition[1]};
}

private double[] getTopRightPoint(GameObject gameObject) {
    return new double[] {gameObject.actualPosition[0] + gameObject.getCurrentSprite().getWidth(), gameObject.actualPosition[1] + gameObject.getCurrentSprite().getHeight()};
}
```

Then whenever time advances I check for collision with the following method:

```
    gameObjects.stream().forEach(o1 -> gameObjects.stream().forEach(o2 -> {
        if (o1 != o2 && o1.intersectsWith(o2)) {
          o1.collision(o2);
        }
      }));
```

This should work but It keeps printing the line

```
 System.out.println("COLLISION BETWEEN " + this.getClass().getSimpleName() + " and "+ other.getClass().getSimpleName());
```

This tells me that there is always a collision even though there isn't.

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 0):

If your coordinates are Bottom X Left your actual getTopRightPoint implementation returns Bottom + Width; Left + Height, that will be actually outside the object bounds.

The correct is: Bottom - height = top; Left + Width = Right

```
private double[] getTopRightPoint(GameObject gameObject) {
    return new double[] {gameObject.actualPosition[0] - gameObject.getCurrentSprite().getHeight(), gameObject.actualPosition[1] + gameObject.getCurrentSprite().getWidth()};
}
```

PS: You also added width to bottom that must be height (and height to left)

Comment: I don't really understand this... my actualposition are my coordinates at the left bottom of my character. So actualposition[0] is the x-position of my character. shouldn't I add the width to get the x position of the right side?

Comment: bottom is the y value, left is the x, maybe you are naming things wrong, but the correct is if you have bottomXleft you need to do bottom-height,left+width, if you use other center point you need to add/subtract according

Comment: If you named things wrong, then your code would be ``` return new double[] {gameObject.actualPosition[0] + gameObject.getCurrentSprite().getWidth(), gameObject.actualPosition[1] - gameObject.getCurrentSprite().getHeight()};```